# Removing ImageView border

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a vertically oriented `LinearLayout` that has a child `LinearLayout` that includes a `TextView`, an `EditText`, and a `Button`,  and a child `ImageView`.

So something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
        <TextView>
        <EditText>
        <Button>
   <ImageView>
```

And the problem I am experiencing is that the seperation between the LinearLayout and the ImageView (displaying a .png as a background with android:background="@drawable/sun") is displaying a visible crease in between them.  I have the LinearLayout  using the same background color as the .png so that it looks like they flow together, but the crease ruins that aspect.

Edit: Here's a screenshot!

[image]

Do you see the thin line under the submit button?

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightblue"

    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/entry" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/hint_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:inputType="text"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Submit"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="0px"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/sunclouds"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/provider"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

(side note, my sun and cloud have rough edges, any quick fixes with gimp?)

Comment: @PetrakovichJ: A screenshot would definitely help. By the way, did you create the PNG image correctly? Sometimes this happens if you do not remove the border of the image while exporting it as a PNG file.

Comment: @Legend: The image was originally a jpg and I used gimp to save it as a png.  I assume it is not the problem you are referring to as the border line is only at the top of the image.

Comment: @PetrakovichJ: I see.. In that case, this could be happening if the ImageView is coming after LinearLayout whose background is set to the png file. I would check if the border is visible for the original PNG background image. Did you by any chance set the background for the inner LinearLayout? Also, could you put in the exact XML you are using? Feel free to put only the relevant parts as this would really help in debugging. As for the gimp thing, I use a different package but if there is an option for anti-aliasing, that could help. But again, it really depends on the original JPG quality.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the line isn't in the image itself?

Comment: Let me fulfill all these requests/verifications and I'll get back to you both.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error you have. I'm quite sure it is the image.

Comment: @PetrakovichJ: Same here... Not able to replicate it...

Comment: Well, that was it, for some reason there was a thin bar at the top of the image, I just painted over it with gimp.  Thank you everyone, I should have tried that before posting but I didn't suspect such a random thin line.

Comment: @PetrakovichJ: Glad it was of help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a reference for someone who does not have the patience to go through the comments, the real problem was that the exported image had a thin line which the OP had corrected. In any case, the following are the list of reasons why this could happen:

- The exported image has a thin line - This can usually be solved by drawing a small rectangle over the line. If not, then slice a 1px version of the image and put it on top of this line to cover it up. It generally works fine.
- When exporting if you set the line color - To solve this remove the line color. Either set it to the same color as the image or remove it altogether.